# page load select dropdown box option automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<select name="optionSnoInput" class="chosen-select" onchange="goodsViewController.option_price_display(this);">
    <option value="">option</option>
    <option value="104">A</option>
    <option value="105">B</option>
    <option value="106">C</option>
    <option value="107">D</option>
    <option value="108">count</option>
</select>
```

On the above dropdown,
I want last option 'count' is automatically selected
because I need counting each product's selling Quantity

but my shop program is counting Quantity as option not product

so I add 'count' option, and use 'display:none' css code..

Please suggest!

Thanks.

Comment: Add `selected` attribute to the last `option` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with JQuery this way to:

```
$(window).on('load', function(){
  $('.chosen-select option:last-child').attr('selected','selected');
})
```

```js
$(window).on('load', function(){
  $('.chosen-select option:last-child').attr('selected','selected');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="optionSnoInput" class="chosen-select" onchange="goodsViewController.option_price_display(this);">
    <option value="">option</option>
    <option value="104">A</option>
    <option value="105">B</option>
    <option value="106">C</option>
    <option value="107">D</option>
    <option value="108">count</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `selected` for the default option.

```
<option value="108" selected>count</option>
```